# Trying to compile Magic Set Editor

Tags: compiling, c++, boost

When I try to compile [magicseteditor](http://magicseteditor.sourceforge.net) I get these errors:

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./src    -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wx/include/base-unicode-debug-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXDEBUG__ -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -pthread  -I. -Wall  -O2 -MT ./src/magicseteditor-main.o -MD -MP -MF     ./src/.deps/magicseteditor-main.Tpo -c -o ./src/magicseteditor-main.o `test -f './src/main.cpp' || echo './'`./src/main.cpp
In file included from ./src/util/prec.hpp:96:0,
             from ./src/main.cpp:9:
./src/util/string.hpp:20:38: fatal error: boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/magicseteditor-main.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though at [the Sourceforge page](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/magicseteditor/mse-linux32-2011-02-05-full.tar.gz) there is a `tar.gz` that you can extract and use the install script to install the program, I had problems with it, so it is indeed best to compile a version against the libraries on your system.

Your main compilation problem seems to be the lack of `libboost` development libraries: you can get all of these by running

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

---

**Dependencies**

However, there are a number of other dependencies and build dependencies that are necessary for the program, so here's how I successfully compiled it on Ubuntu 12.04.

First download the necessary prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall subversion
```

Now, install all the build dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev libhunspell-dev libwxgtk2.8-dev libwxbase2.8-dev
```

and then the dependencies for running the program:

```
sudo apt-get install libhunspell-1.3-0 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 libboost-system1.48.0 libboost-regex1.48.0
```

If you have any problems running the program you will probably just need another `libboost` related shared library; refer to [this thread on the program's forum](http://magicseteditor.sourceforge.net/node/5073).

**Note:** These lists of packages relate to those on 12.04; the versions of the libboost libraries (and others) may be different on later Ubuntu versions.

**Compilation**

I presume you checked out the code from svn by entering

```
svn co https://magicseteditor.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/magicseteditor/trunk magicseteditor
```

Then `cd` in terminal to the `magicseteditor` folder, and simply run

```
./configure && make
```

If you wish to set a prefix where it is to be installed or wish to select another configure option, run `./configure --help` before you run `./configure && make`.

Now just run

```
sudo checkinstall --pkgversion=2.0
```

**However**, after that you must also install the data folders into `~/.magicseteditor`, as `checkinstall` did not seem to install that data. So make sure `~/.magicseteditor` exists, and make sure you are in the magicseteditor folder where you compiled it, and run:

```
cp -r data/ ~/.magicseteditor/
mkdir ~/.magicseteditor/resource
cp -r src/resource/msw/cursor/ ~/.magicseteditor/resource
cp -r src/resource/msw/icon/ ~/.magicseteditor/resource
cp -r src/resource/msw/tool/ ~/.magicseteditor/resource
cp -r src/resource/msw/other/* ~/.magicseteditor/resource
cp -r src/resource/common/* ~/.magicseteditor/resource
```

Make sure no mistakes are made when copying these across, as the directory structure is important.

**Again**, these commands will only work if you are in the magicseteditor folder in which you compiled it. (Indeed there does seem to be a `Resources.sh` in the magicseteditor folder that can be used to install the data, but it does not install the data directory, so I should use the commands above, which will install everything you need instead.)

It also seems that you need the fonts from the [other package](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/magicseteditor/mse-linux32-2011-02-05-full.tar.gz), so download it, move to its containing folder, and extract it with

```
tar -xzvf mse-linux32-2011-02-05-full.tar.gz
```

cd to the folder and run

```
cp fonts/* ~/.fonts
```

Now run `magicseteditor &` and the screenshots such as those below will appear.

[image]

[image]